# Convert Enums to List of given type

Tags: c#, list, enums

I have an enum and I want to map it to a list of a given type.

```cs
 public enum ExampleEnum
        {
            A =   1,
            B =   2,
            C =   4,
            D =   8,
            E =   16,
            F =   32,
            G =   64,
        }
```

With this Example Enum, I then want to put it into a List of type `ListItem` that looks like this:

```cs
 public class ListItem
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
List<ListItem> ExampleList = new List<ListItem>() {     
      new ListItem(){Text = "A",   Value = 1},
      new ListItem(){Text = "B",   Value = 2},
      new ListItem(){Text = "C",   Value = 4},
      new ListItem(){Text = "D",   Value = 8},
      new ListItem(){Text = "E",   Value = 16},
      new ListItem(){Text = "F",   Value = 32},
      new ListItem(){Text = "G",   Value = 64},
    };
```

However, currently I am just creating a list that essentially contains the same information as the Enum, I want to create the list from the Enum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be a better way, but this seems to work:

```
var list = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ExampleEnum)).Cast<ExampleEnum>().Select(
    x => new ListItem { Text = x.ToString(), Value = (int)x }).ToList();
```

So this will grab all the values from the enum using `Enum.GetValues`. Since it returns type `Array`, I use `Cast<ExampleEnum>` to get them in to a `IEnumerable<ExampleEnum>`. Then I `Select` each enum value to a `ListItem` type. `Text` property is created by using `ToString`, `Value` property is created by casting it to `int`.